# Perl script in linux environment is not working via cron

Tags: linux, perl, cron

When I try to run a Perl script which is called via Linux script manually it works fine but not executable via CRON.

Linux_scrip.sh conatains Perl_script and the command is,

```
perl_path/perl Perl_script.pl
```

I got perl_path using `which perl` command.

Can anyone suggest why is it not executable via `CRON` entry.

Comment: what is the error ? what is in crontab ?

Comment: The first thing to do whenever a cronjob "isn't working" is to check the cron logs. On my system, the log is in `/var/log/cron`, but it could be different for you. That will tell you if the job is actually being run, and if so, any errors it might be generating.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely suspects:

- Current work directory isn't as expected.
- Permission issues<sup>[1]</sup>.
- Environment variables aren't setup as expected.
- Requirement of a terminal can't be met.

See the [`crontab` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) for more pitfalls and some debugging tips.

The first thing you should do is to read the error message.

---

1. This isn't likely to be an issue for you own `cron` job, but I've included it since it's quite a common problem for scripts run from other services.

Comment: The [`crontab` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) has a longer laundry list of debugging tips.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable cause is current working directory.

Before perl command execution, write a command to change directory.

Something like :

```
cd  perl_path;

perl Perl_script.pl
```